# How to pass database value through to template in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am making a store that sells shoes, clothes and accessories as a project for school, but whenever I try to pass a variable through from views.py to my html template file, it come up with a weird value.

[image]

Code of html file:

```
    {% block content %}
    <h1>List of Shoes:</h1>
    {% for shoe_type in all_shoes %}
      <h1>{{all_shoes}}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Code of views.py:

```
def index(request, *args, **kwargs):
    target_page = './html/index.html'

    all_shoes = Shoes.objects.all()
    all_accessories = Accessories.objects.all()
    all_clothes = Clothing.objects.all()

    context = {
    "all_shoes" : all_shoes,
    "all_accessories" : all_accessories,
    "all_clothing" : all_clothes,
    }



    return render(request, target_page, context)
```

Code of the models.py: (please note I haven't migrated the clothing part to my new naming scheme yet)

```
class Clothing(models.Model):
    ITEM_CONDITION = [('MINT','Mint') , ('AMAZING','Amazing') ,  ('GOOD','Good') , ('BAD','Bad') , ('TERRIBLE','Terrible')]
    Type = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Type of clothing:')
    Brand = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Brand of item')
    Price = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Price of item')
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Description of item')
    Picture = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    Condition = models.CharField(choices=ITEM_CONDITION, max_length=16, default='MINT', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Condition')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Clothing'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Clothing'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Brand + ' ' + self.Type

class Shoes(models.Model):
    ITEM_CONDITION = [('MINT','Mint') , ('AMAZING','Amazing') ,  ('GOOD','Good') , ('BAD','Bad') , ('TERRIBLE','Terrible')]
    shoe_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Type of shoe:')
    shoe_brand = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Brand of shoe')
    shoe_price = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Price of shoe')
    shoe_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Description of shoe')
    shoe_picture = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    shoe_condition = models.CharField(choices=ITEM_CONDITION, max_length=16, default='MINT', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Shoe'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Shoes'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.shoe_brand + ' ' + self.shoe_type

class Accessories(models.Model):
    ITEM_CONDITION = [('MINT', 'Mint') , ('AMAZING', 'Amazing') , ('GOOD', 'Good') , ('BAD', 'Bad') , ('TERRIBLE', 'Terrbile')]
    accessory_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Type of accessory')
    accessory_brand = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Brand of accessory')
    accessory_price = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Price of accessory')
    accessory_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Description of accessory.')
    accessory_picture = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    accessory_condition = models.CharField(choices=ITEM_CONDITION, max_length=16, default='MINT', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Condition')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Accessory'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Accessories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Brand + ' ' + self.Type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% block content %}
<h1>List of Shoes:</h1>
{% for shoe in all_shoes %}
  <h1>{{shoe.shoe_type}}</h1>
  <p>{{shoe.shoe_brand}}<p>
  <p>{{------------}}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

you can add your field similar way

Comment: Thanks! I copy and pasted this into my html and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the scene, what you are passing to html through jinja is set of objects
wrapped in a object "all_shoes". This object contains dict of each shoes as
described in model with keys like shoe_type, shoe_brand, shoe_size etc.....
so you have to call values of each key by applying syntax "shoe_type.type"
in for loop (note for shoe_type in all_shoes: doesnt call type values of shoes
in fact shoe_type will be a object containing key and values of descriptors)

Also to well represent the table to details try using   tag

## ---------------------------------------------------------------

```
{% block content %}
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
  <th>Type</th>
  <th>Brand</th>
  <th>Price</th>
</tr>


{% for obj in all_shoes %}
<tr>
  <th>obj.shoe_type</th>
  <th>obj.shoe_brand</th>
  <th>obj.shoe_price</th>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

```css
table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
table#t01 th {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Brand</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Formal</td>
    <td>Redson</td>
    <td>$94</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Sports</td>
    <td>Adidas</td>
    <td>$104</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jogger</td>
    <td>Puma</td>
    <td>$84</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I wanted the data to be passed into without a table for aesthetic looks, but the issue I was having was the {% for shoe_type in all_shoes %} which I thought I tried, but I must not have, thanks anyway.